# Split multiple lines of the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Device details
device = "test"
user = "abc"
password = "123"

# Invoking remote session
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(device, username=user, password=password)

# std commands to capture shell output
channel = client.invoke_shell()
stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
stdout = channel.makefile('rb')

# remote commands to run
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('vmm ping | grep no-response')
noresponse = stdout.read()
print noresponse
#print some_string.split('', 1)[0]

noresponse = noresponse.split(' ', 1)[0]
print noresponse


# Close connections
stdout.close()
stdin.close()
client.close()
```

Output:

```
> C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Python/Scripts/Login to Unix3.py"

R1_MPC00 10.49.123.146 no-response
R3_MPC00 10.49.122.24 no-response
R6_re 10.49.122.226 no-response
R7_re 10.49.122.217 no-response
R8_re 10.49.122.215 no-response
R11_MPC00 10.49.122.20 no-response
R14_re 10.49.122.152 no-response
R14_MPC00 10.49.122.151 no-response
R17_MPC00 10.49.122.129 no-response
R19_re 10.49.121.213 no-response
R20_re 10.49.121.206 no-response
SW2_MPC00 10.49.120.54 no-response
R1_MPC00
```

Question:

I need first word from all the lines of the output, not just `R1_MPC00`.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your definition of a word?

Answer (score 1):

```
pattern = r'[^.*\s]*'

with open('test.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
         match = re.search(pattern, line)
         if match:
             print(match.group())
```

There *was* a comment that you could just split along the newlines and then the spaces with a list comprehension, which would probably be easier, but why do that when you can do it with regex?

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    words = [x for x in [l.split(' ')[0] for l in file.read().split('\n')] if x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split on space for each line in the contents of `noresponse`:

```
noresponse = """\
R1_MPC00 10.49.123.146 no-response
R3_MPC00 10.49.122.24 no-response
R6_re 10.49.122.226 no-response
R7_re 10.49.122.217 no-response
R8_re 10.49.122.215 no-response
R11_MPC00 10.49.122.20 no-response
R14_re 10.49.122.152 no-response
R14_MPC00 10.49.122.151 no-response
R17_MPC00 10.49.122.129 no-response
R19_re 10.49.121.213 no-response
R20_re 10.49.121.206 no-response
SW2_MPC00 10.49.120.54 no-response
"""

for line in noresponse.splitlines():
    print(line.split(' ', 1)[0])
```